# How do i select all from database and do while loop with them

Tags: database

I did this easy select and im getting Error: Call to a member function fetchAssoc() on boolean , im beginner, im just trying to pull out two variables and make operations with them.

```
$result = db_select('cities', 'c')
        ->fields('c')
        ->execute()
        ->fetchAssoc();



  while ($row = $result->fetchAssoc()) {

    $city_id = $row['city_id'];
  $city_name = $row['city_name'];
```

Only this is working for me

```
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM {cities}";
           $result = db_query($sql);

  while ($row = $result->fetchAssoc()) {

    $city_id = $row['city_id'];
  $city_name = $row['city_name'];
```

Comment: You already called fetchAssoc in the first example. Check the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
   $results = db_select('cities', 'c')
    ->fields('c')
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

   foreach ($results as $result){
    $city_id = $result['city_id'];
    $city_name = $result['city_name'];
   }
```